# Postfix routinely references both smtp and smtpd in configuration files. What is the difference?

Tags: postfix, email-server

**Environment:** Postfix 3.3

In my `main.cf` file I see references to both `smtp` and `smtpd`.

For example:

`smtpd` security is set here.

```
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
```

And just a few lines below `smtp` security is set in an otherwise identical parameter.

```
smtp_tls_security_level = may
```

Other examples are these `smtpd` parameters:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file
smtpd_tls_key_file
```

Although these aren't exactly the same just a few lines below `smtp` is used.

```
smtp_tls_CApath
smtp_tls_CAfile
```

**Question:**  As far as Postfix is concerned what is the difference between `smtp` and `smtpd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, but generally **smtpd** handles receiving incoming mail, and **smtp** handles sending outgoing mail. The confusing naming probably stems from the fact that the SMTP protocol is used by both, the former acts as a server, and the latter as a client.